# Android project converting to isLibrary

Tags: java, android

Hello i want to convert [ebookdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/) to a library. When I mark it as library i could use its classes in my project. However in ebookdroid when app is loaded Ebookdroid class which extends Aplication is called. This class init app Settings. So is it possible to call this init class from my project if ebookdroid is Library ?

When I try to do this:

```
EBookDroidApp app = (EBookDroidApp)getApplication();
app.init();
```

I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Application class in AndroidManifest.xml. This way, when the application is launched, Android will know what class to use. By default, Android will always use `Application`, which can not be cast to `EBookDroidApp`.

[See this answer for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338739/210526)

Comment: So how to start this EBookDroidApp which extends Application if i use that project as library ?